# Bitlocker-encrypted Windows and LUKS-encypted Xubuntu in Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, uefi, encryption

Company policies instruct me to use a Bitlocker encrypted Windows 10 (No turning off Secure Boot), but I also use Linux, which has to be LUKS encrypted. Now I need to set this system up for Dual-Boot on my Thinkpad W550s.

The encryption key for Windows is stored on the TPM, Secure Boot and UEFI Boot has to be enabled. I have planned to store Windows 10 on SDB (SSD, 250GB) and Ubuntu on SDA (HDD, 500GB, actually 250GB since I want to use the other half as common unencrypted data partition for not-security-relevant data).

That's my situation. I have tried installing Windows 10, leave it unencrypted and install Ubuntu, encrypted, but unfortunately GRUB2 completely messes up and doesn't boot Windows anymore. So I couldnt even get to the point where I encrypt Windows.

> /EndEntire file path: /ACPI(a0341d0,0)/PCI(2,1f)/UnknownMessaging(12) /HD(2,c8800,96000,fe030bf1430a6047,9a,9a)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot) /File(bkpbootmgfw.efi)/EndEntire error: cannot load image.

or

> /EndEntire file path: /ACPI(a0341d0,0)/PCI(2,1f)/UnknownMessaging(12) /HD(2,c8800,96000,fe030bf1430a6046,9a,9a)/File(\EFI\Boot) /File(bkpbootx64.efi)/EndEntire error: cannot load image.

Changing the boot order is pretty much not an option since it has to be locked, which would require me to go into the BIOS, disable the lock, change bootorder and enable the lock again.

Has anybody been in the same super-annoying situation and found a solution? :)

Thanks in advance guys!

**TL;DR:**

**SDB: LUKS-Ubuntu, 50% of SDA: Bitlocker-Windows (Key on TPM), 50% of SDA: Common Data Storage, Secure-Boot & EFI has to be enabled, No changing boot order in BIOS, Thinkpad W550s, Help?**

Comment: I feel most of the machines are running  to  like Windows XP or Windows 7 in our Government machinery in India and most of them use gmail. means a webmail

Comment: and also Windows 8.1

Comment: Not helpful, even if I would use Windows 7, I would have to figure out this Dualboot Situation.

Comment: Sounds real complicated. Even if you *did* find a workaround, you may *still* get into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Put Windows on sda and only install grub2 on sdb where you'll have Linux.

Leave the 250GB data partition unsecured. Doesn't sound like a problem